# User login block doesn't appear for authenticated user

Tags: 7, blocks

Well, I go to structure/blocks/User Login/configuration and I tried select all checkboxes in "Show block for specific roles" but login form doesn't appear when user has status "authenticated".

How I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user login block will never appear for any user other than anonymous users, as users are already logged in, so it makes no sense to have a login block when they are already logged in.

Comment: This is correct. Same reason why you can't access the login path.

Comment: ok, I have a registration form with one field (email) on the index page. What I can do for it doesn't hide when user is logged in?

Comment: This is the same issue - if a user is already logged in, they don't need to register, so the registration block is not going to show.

Comment: maybe, here is way to create a different form like user registration, because when it disappears my page lose look.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your talking about the menu with current user informations("my account","log out").
If that is the case the block you'r looking for is called "USER MENU".